# Reactjs: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

Whats wrong with my code?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
// import {connect} from 'react-redux';
// import List_items from './list_items';



// @connect(item => ({data: state.example.data}))
class Home extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataOperations: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/Selectallbarang/?format=json')
   .then(results => { 
    return results.json();
      }).then(data => {
          let dataOperations = data.results.map((idk) => {
            return(
              <h1 key={idk.results}>

              {idk.harga_satuan}

              </h1>
              )
          })
         this.setState({dataOperations: dataOperations});
         console.log("state", this.state.id);
        })
      }
```

I get the error code like below

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
(anonymous function)

```
C:/Users/kurniawan/django/shemura/frontend/src/home/Home.js:23
  20 |   .then(results => { 
  21 |    return results.json();
  22 |      }).then(data => {
> 23 |          let dataOperations = data.results.map((idk) => {
  24 |            return(
  25 |              <h1 key={idk.results}>
  26 |
```

View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.

Comment: are you sure there's a results property on the json data you're fetching?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `data.results.map` by `(data.results || []).map`

---

Because this error means `data.results` is undefined, then `data.results.map` is property (method) cannot be read from that undefined.

There are many ways to handle that, however, I assume I gave you the most **elegant** way.